# Does anyone have experience in simulating reinforced concrete member in AceGen and AceFEM?

Tags: acegen

I am going to start generating an acegen code in which the flexural behaviour of a reinforced concrete beam can be simulated. Since there is no documentary about reinforced concrete members in AceGEN manual, I would like to ask if any of you has some sort of experience about this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This PhD [thesis](http://drugg.fgg.uni-lj.si/4536/) could be interesting for you. Maybe you could also post a prototype of your code and ask more specific question about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look on that.

Comment: This thesis is exactly what I need for my future studies. Is it yours?

Comment: I am glad you find it useful. No, it is my friend's.

Comment: I was wondering if you can help me to get access to the AceGen codes of this thesis so that it will help me build my own based on its structure.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot provide you the codes. I suggest that you start experimenting with the simplest beam elements and then continue to more involved cases. You can find some examples of beam elements in this [book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319390031) . Also I think you can get better answers on this site if you ask more specific questions, supported with minimal working examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will start working and that. In the future, I will post many questions regarding my improvements.